# Why is accuracy so much lower when using fitcecoc() compared to trainImage​CategoryCl​assifier()​?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, svm, face-recognition

I am trying to use bag of words and fitcecoc() (multiclass SVM) to reproduce similar results to those obtained by using Image Category classifier
[as seen in the documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-bag-of-features.).

```
% Code from documentation
bag = bagOfFeatures(trainingSet); % create bag of features from trainingSet (an image datastore)
categoryClassifier = trainImageCategoryClassifier(trainingSet, bag);
confMatrix = evaluate(categoryClassifier, validationSet);
```

This returns accuracy of ~98% on the validation set.

However when I pass the histogram of visual word occurrences into the multiclass SVM classifier it has ~2.5% accuracy.

```
SVM_SURF = fitcecoc(trainFeatures,trainingSet.Labels);
bag = bagOfFeatures(validationSet);
featureMatrix = encode(bag, validationSet); % histogram of visual word occurrences
[pred score cost] = predict(SVM_SURF, featureMatrix)
accuracy = sum(validationSet.Labels == pred)/size(validationSet.Labels,1);
accuracy
```

Is there an obvious reason as to why the accuracy is so much lower when bag of words is passed into fitcecoc() rather than trainImageCategoryClassifier()?

Answer (score 1):

The fitcecoc classifier is a multi-purpose (image, financial data, ...`) classifier. By configuring the kernel you can get better accuracy rates. However, traditionally, the fitcecoc function gives much better results if you increase the training data.